# Why resampling for pandas different while using cumsum?

Tags: python, pandas

for example, If I want to do resampling for below using the sum for 1 day, I get expected results (5 data points)

```
idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)

data_sum= ts.resample('1d').agg(['sum'])
```

But, I get 100 datapoints for cumsum eventhough I did resampling for 1 day using the same approach.

```
data_cumsum= ts.resample('1d').agg(['cumsum'])
```

isn't it suppose to return only 5 data points ? Why cumsum is behaving differently than other aggs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple - most functions aggregate data like `sum`, `mean`, but some not like `cumsum`, `diff`, `ffill`, `bfill`.

So it is reason for difference in `resample` and also in `groupby`.

Here is possible use [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) - it repeat resampled data, so got 100rows, for cumulative sum is not resampler implemented, so used alternative with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
data_sum= ts.resample('1d').transform('sum')
data_cumsum= ts.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1d')).cumsum()

print (data_sum)
2018-01-01 00:00:00     276
2018-01-01 01:00:00     276
2018-01-01 02:00:00     276
2018-01-01 03:00:00     276
2018-01-01 04:00:00     276

2018-01-04 23:00:00    2004
2018-01-05 00:00:00     390
2018-01-05 01:00:00     390
2018-01-05 02:00:00     390
2018-01-05 03:00:00     390
Freq: H, Length: 100, dtype: int64

print (data_cumsum)
2018-01-01 00:00:00       0
2018-01-01 01:00:00       1
2018-01-01 02:00:00       3
2018-01-01 03:00:00       6
2018-01-01 04:00:00      10

2018-01-04 23:00:00    2004
2018-01-05 00:00:00      96
2018-01-05 01:00:00     193
2018-01-05 02:00:00     291
2018-01-05 03:00:00     390
Freq: H, Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is there any better way to return only 5 data points for cumsum too using above resample function so that, I can use multiple aggs at once such [min,max,cumsum]. something like this ?

Comment: @user3280146 - Not easy combine this 2 different kind of functions, it is possible but loggically problematic.

Comment: @user3280146 - hmm, can you add expected output? Because maybe `agg` changed to `transform` for aggregate fucntions like `sum` should help

Comment: hmm I think by tweaking the functions in sum seems to be work for the cumsum too. tried and it seems to be working :)